# Non-execution of statement in function calling

Tags: r, function

While working on some problem i came across a situation in which i wanted to know if a function was executed when called upon. To do so i put a print statement in the function.

```
abc = function(x)
    if(x > 0) {
      return(x)
      print("Go")
    } else {
      return(0)
      print("Run")
    }

y = abc(3)
y
# [1] 3
```

Why print statement is not executed while calling abc()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are `return`ing before `print`ing. Change the sequence of those two statements and it should print

```
abc = function(x) {
    if(x > 0) {
      print("Go")
      return(x)
    } else {
      print("Run")
      return(0)
   }
}

abc(3)
#[1] "Go"
#[1] 3

abc(-3)
#[1] "Run"
#[1] 0
```